# how do I tell rails to not render html for json requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I make a curl request to my api endpoint and there is a problem (in development), then I see:

```
>curl --user me:mypassword http://localhost:3000/api/v1/magic_endpoint.json

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
  <style>
  ... stuff
    <body>

    <header>
      <h1>
        ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
      </h1>
    </header>
  ... more stuff
```

Which is really annoying and obnoxious.  How can I tell rails to not to return HTML when json was what was asked for?  I have seen many questions similar to this on here with answers that say to redirect your 404/500 in routes.rb to a custom errors controller and manually render json with 'internal error' or 'not found', but I do not want to do that.  Rails is outputting the actual error, in this case, **ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError**, and I don't want to hide that.. I just don't want to have to visually parse a bunch of html markup to figure out what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what das-g suggested, I decided to just write a function in my .bashrc that I called "crimp" as it's related to curl (ha ha):

```
crimp() {
  curl $@ | lynx -stdin
}
```

So now I can do:

crimp --user me:secret http://localhost:3000/api/v1/my_endpoint.json

and I don't have to read through obnoxious html tags anymore.

Comment: what is lynx here?

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
```

to your `config/environments/development.rb`, but that'd turn off the exception-to-response conversion completely, so you wouldn't even get a HTTP status code, and certainly no trace of the exception in the response's body.

I guess what you actually want is for the exception-to-response conversion to 'magically' happen, still, but with JSON as a result. I don't think stock Rails can be configured to do that (short of monkey-patching `ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper`, where this particular magic happens). But there might be gems (Ruby libraries) that provide Rails engines that enable Rails to do just what you want.

### Does it have to be `curl`?

To explore the behavior of your API implementation, writing automated [tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) or [request specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) might be better suited than manually querying it with `curl`. And the ones that pin down the wanted behavior can then just be kept around and be run during development, so that they'll tell you when the behavior unexpectedly changes.

Comment: Yeah, I do not want to turn off exceptions, and I do have automated request specs and integration tests.  The point is, when one asks for json, it seems really weird, wrong, and annoying to get back html.  Large projects with multiple apps communicating via endpoint cannot rely completely on automated integration tests.  There needs to be some form of real-world user testing in the development environment.  When I have something like a pending migration error, it just is seems really obnoxious to have to read through a whole page of html, stylesheets, etc just to see what is wrong.

Comment: While it won't help about _feeling_ wrong to get HTML when expecting JSON, you can do something easy against the obnoxiousness of reading raw HTML: Just let `curl` write a file to disc instead of spitting stuff out on `stdout`, then open the file with your favorite web browser.

Comment: Also, if you're using JetBrain's Ruby IDE *RubyMine*, it features a neat REST client (Menu `Tools` > `Test RESTful Web Service`). Responses are shown as raw text by default, but at the left edge of the response panel, there's a `Open response content in Browser` button. Other IDEs might include similar functionality, either built in or as plugins/add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your controller you can do something like:

```
  rescue_from StandardError do |ex|
    if request.format.json?
      render text: ex.message
    else
      raise ex
    end
  end
```

But there are some side-effects doing this, for example the exception won't show in the logs. (But you can log manually of course).

Comment: Ugh.  Yeah, that's not at all what I want to do.  I think the real answer is to make a pull request and make rails not render a template for json requests when ActionController blows up..  But I won't bother doing that because I know that pull request will just sit there forever and eventually Jose Valim will say something like "I don't agree that json requests should not return HTML responses"...  So much for open source.

Comment: besides, an error like ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError will not be caught by a rescue_from like that in the controller.